# Are pans allowed in hand luggage?

Tags: airports, europe, airport-transfer, airport-security, berlin

I am traveling via Easy Jet from Berlin airport. am I allowed to take metal/steel pans + sandwich maker in my hand luggage?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Larger metal objects in hand luggage](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/20130/larger-metal-objects-in-hand-luggage)

Comment: The accepted answer to the question linked by David is as much official info as you can get. As an anecdote, I personally flew several times in the EU with a carry-on full of pots, pans and other kitchen implements and nobody batted an eyelid. It's hard to imagine you could hijack a plane using a pan, so you shouldn't have trouble convincing curious security people that these are not on the forbidden list. However, leave extra time for the security check as your luggage might get selected for thorough examination, which can easily take half an hour.

Answer (score 2):

In my personal experience, I have travelled several times in the EU with metal pans (and even cutlery at times) in my carry-on, heading for a camping trip.
I have never had issues with it, but it seems to vary according to airports and people who check your bag.
I agree with @TooTea. Not a very formal reply, but pans do not seem to be strictly regulated on planes.
Hope it helps!